# Character "[" (altgr+F) not appearing in the client?

Tags: visual-studio-code

So, after downloading and trying out Visual Studio Code, one issue was critical to me:

I could not do "[]". 
The "]" part appears correctly, the "[" however, does not.

The command for "[" is <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.
I have tried tinkering with the keyboard shortcuts, but this is not a shortcut. The only shortcut that causes similar issues with other IDEs is when <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> is mapped and you have a Hungarian keyboard that somehow makes these overlap. However, I see no option of completely removing shortcuts, only adding new ones. Setting this particular shortcut to "" does not help either.

Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to remap action.format to some other key, and "disable" <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> key.
On non-english keyboards: `Ctrl+Alt ≈ AltGr`.
Add something like this to your keybindings.json:

```
  {
    "key": "shift+alt+f",
    "command": "editor.action.format",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+alt+f"
  }
```